# How to solve NullPointerException error in Android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

The below code runs smoothly in the emulator from Eclipse, but there are problems when I run it on my Android phone and tablet.

```
public class RingerActivity extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button press;
boolean tone = true;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(RingerActivity.this, R.raw.alarm);
    //Error occurs at here
    mp.start();

    Handler h = new Handler();
    Runnable stopPlaybackRun = new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }    
    };
    h.postDelayed(stopPlaybackRun, 20 * 1000);

    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(manager!=null){
        manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        int maxVolume = manager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, 0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I get a "NullPointException" in line "mp.start()". I have been working on this problem for a while, but I really do not know what is happening, I tried this on both my Android smartphone and tablet (Gingerbread and ICS), but the app force closes. I need help from you guys... thanks...

Logcat

```
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testing.ringer/com.testing.ringer.RingerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at com.testing.ringer.RingerActivity.onCreate(RingerActivity.java:23)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
11-09 15:41:09.909: E/AndroidRuntime(11975):    ... 11 more
```

Ringer Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testing.ringer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".RingerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could share the log.
I guess the issue willnot be there if you call the mp.start in a handler with some small delay

Comment: I find that mp = new MediaPlayer(); is unnecessary ; MediaPlayer.create(RingerActivity.this, R.raw.alarm); returns the media player object anyways.

Comment: try just keeping two lines mp = MediaPlayer.create(RingerActivity.this, R.raw.alarm);
mp.start();  after setContentView and see if it fails still.

Comment: your code is working fine, I tested in emulator and device too, in which device you are testing?

Comment: i tested it on HTC Desire HD (Gingerbread) as well as Samsung Galaxy Tab (ICS)

Comment: @TusharVengurlekar i already tried your method, still failed

Comment: I tested in HTC explorer 2.3.5, its works, do one thing, uninstall and then try.

Comment: One possibility is that the mp3 file is not copied to device as the mp3 file was added later and you just executed the app again rather than doing uninstall and install after adding mp3 file. In this case do uninstall and install again as Robinhood has suggested.

Comment: What was wrong with this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13302735/1626878. stop posting similar questions for the same problem.

Comment: did you properly declare your activity in manifest file? have once look.

Comment: the manifest is attached

Comment: try using `mp.prepare()` before `mp.start()`?

Comment: Code working fine,the that mp pointing location is null.Add any mp3 alaram on the location.

Answer (score 6):

NullPointerException means that mp is null. This means the MediaPlayer.create() failed. Does R.raw.alarm exist?

Comment: yes... i created a raw file in res, and put the alarm.mp3 inside

Comment: and the alarm is exist in R.java

Comment: If R.raw.alarm does not exist the code wouldn't work with emulator.

Answer (score 1):

[NullPointerException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), cause when there is no instance or array to use, the best to trace is to `put breakpoint and debug your code`.

Seem your code is perfect, just make sure whether `.mp3` is exist or not? and you perfectly kept inside `raw` folder.

At last try to uninstall your existing and then clean your project and run. good luck.

Comment: the "uninstall your existing" means uninstall the application from my android phone right? All the things u mentioned earlier i have done, but still not working in my phone, i have attached the logcat...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try cleaning the project ??
Newly added resources show up in the package explorer only after cleaning the project.