# android studio 2.3 gradle project sync failed. basic functionality will not work

Tags: android

I have recently downloaded the Android studio (2.3) and it gives the below error. can anyone help me?

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
                build file '/Users/shervinkoulena/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloWorld3/app/build.gradle': 1: expecting EOF, found ':' @ line 1, column 14.
                5apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Sorry, I am very new to programming. I am also using a mac if it helps. This is the build.grade content I see:

```
    5apply plugin:

    'com.android.application' android {
     compileSdkVersion 25
     buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shervinkoulena.helloworld"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),              'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
        }
       }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       }
```

Comment: You probably are missing `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` as the error says or you have not formatted gradle structure well. YOu need to post gradle file so we can help

Comment: Post the gradle code if the below answer and above comment doesn't work for you.

Comment: I posted the build.gradle code. I am using a mac if it's relevant

Answer (score 1):

write this line in build.gradle `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: the build.gradle file has this line at the beginning

Comment: 5apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Cannot invoke method android() on null object

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303544/how-to-solve-nullpointerexception-error-in-android) for this problem....the problem you asked in this question is solved

Comment: and for this problem you'll have to share your code and logcat

Comment: I haven't written any code. This happened when I opened the Android studio for the first time. Where do I get logcat? sorry, I am very new to this.

Comment: logcat is where android studio show errors.....its in the bottom menu named android monitor