# Null Pointer Exception on Getting Content Resolver from DaggerApplication

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have created a custom DaggerApplication class and have written the adequate AppModule and AppComponent classes for it, but I get null pointer exception upon accessing my `injected` context's content resolver. (which is my global application context). I have tried to shrink my problem into a small example in the following lines of codes.

Here is my application class:

```
class CustomPlayerApplication @Inject constructor() : DaggerApplication() {
    companion object{
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        lateinit var context: Context
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = this
    }

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this).build()
    }
}
```

Here is my AppModule:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesLibraryManager(application: CustomPlayerApplication): LibraryManager {
        return LibraryManager(application).apply{
               createContentResolver()
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my app component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<CustomPlayerApplication> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun create(app: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
    fun libraryManager(): LibraryManager
}
```

This is my libraryManager class.

```
class LibraryManager @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) { 
    fun createContentResolver(): ContentResolver? {
        return context.contentResolver
    }
}
```

Upon calling the contentResolver, the app crashes with a null pointer exception, stating that I cannot call contentResolver on a null object. While debugging, I have found out that here the context is not null, but I  also cannot call its contentResolver.

I know for sure that before changing my class to DaggerApplication and using 2.24, my code was working. Whatever that is happening is probably because of the `@bindInstance` annotation, but I couldn't find any related issues.

EDIT: To further explain my problem, while the provides method is called in the 'AppModule`, the app crashes because the`context.ContentResolver` is called on a null object reference, while context is not null and its actually my application context. I'm a bit puzzled that what might the actual problem will be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve NullPointerException error in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303544/how-to-solve-nullpointerexception-error-in-android)

Comment: @Ashish Reading the link you've put here, my problem is not similar at all. Not all `null pointer exceptions` must come from similar problems! This is caused by an inconsistency in how I have implemented my injection classes.

Comment: If you get an exception please _always_ include the stacktrace in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use `AndroidInjector.Factory` instead of your `Builder` in `AppComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<CustomPlayerApplication> {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory : AndroidInjector.Factory<CustomPlayerApplication>
}

class CustomPlayerApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    ...

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this)
    }
}
```

Also note that you don't have to annotate the `CustomPlayerApplication`'s constructor with `@Inject`. That annotation is useful only when you let Dagger create instances of the class. Dagger won't create an application object, it is created by OS, so the annotation is redundant.

Having both `@Provider` method and `@Inject` annotated constructor for `LibraryManager` seems quite redundant as well. You can just use one of them.