# How to Solve 'void android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView$OnKeyboardActionListener.onPress(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView$OnKeyboardActionListener.onPress(int)' on a null object reference

> Overrides deprecated method in 'android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener

What is replacement for this class?

This is my code

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, OnKeyboardActionListener, RecognitionListener{

    public void onRelease(int i) {
    }

    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    public void swipeUp() {
    }
    public void swipeLeft() {
        handleBackspace();
    }

    public void swipeDown() {
        handleClose();
    }
    public void onText(CharSequence charSequence) {
        InputConnection currentInputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (currentInputConnection != null) {
            currentInputConnection.beginBatchEdit();
            if (this.mComposing.length() > 0) {
                commitTyped(currentInputConnection);
            }
            currentInputConnection.commitText(charSequence, 0);
            currentInputConnection.endBatchEdit();
            updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
        }
    }
    public void onPress(int i) {
        try {
            if (mInputView!=null){
                for (Key key : this.mInputView.getKeyboard().getKeys()) {
                    if (key.codes[0] == i) {
                        if (key.modifier) {
                            this.mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
                        } else if (KeyboardState.phoneKeyboard == this.mInputView.getKeyboard()) {
                            this.mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
                        } else {
                            this.mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(this.sessionManager.getPopup().booleanValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onKey(int i, int[] iArr) {
        sound_vibrate();
        if (isWordSeparator(i)) {
            if (this.mComposing.length() > 0) {
                commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());
            }
            sendKey(i);
            updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
        } else if (i == -5) {
            handleBackspace();
        } else if (i == -1) {
            handleShift();
        } else if (i == -3) {
            handleClose();
            return;
        } else if (i != -100) {
            if (i == -2 && this.mInputView != null) {
                Keyboard keyboard = this.mInputView.getKeyboard();
                if ((keyboard == this.mSymbolsKeyboard || keyboard == this.mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard) && keyboard != this.mHindiSymbolsKeyboard) {
                    if (Preference.getLangSelect().equals("English")) {
                        setLatinKeyboard(this.mQwertyKeyboard);
                        this.tv_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        this.btnTransliteration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        if (this.sessionManager.getTransliteration().booleanValue()) {
                            this.isEnabled = true;
                        } else {
                            this.isEnabled = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        setLatinKeyboard(this.mOtherKeyboard);
                        this.tv_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        this.btnTransliteration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ll_transliteration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }


                } else if ((keyboard == this.mHindiSymbolsKeyboard || keyboard == this.mHindiSymbolsShiftedKeyboard) && keyboard != this.mSymbolsKeyboard) {
                    setLatinKeyboard(this.mOtherKeyboard);
                    this.tv_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);//Gone
                    this.btnTransliteration.setVisibility(View.GONE);//Gone
                    this.isEnabled = false;
                } else if (keyboard == this.mOtherKeyboard || keyboard == this.mOtherShiftedKeyboard) {
                    setLatinKeyboard(this.mHindiSymbolsKeyboard);
                    this.mHindiSymbolsKeyboard.setShifted(false);
                    this.tv_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);//Gone
                    this.btnTransliteration.setVisibility(View.GONE);//Gone
                    this.isEnabled = false;
                } else {
                    this.tv_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//Gone
                    this.btnTransliteration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//Gone
                    this.isEnabled = false;
                    setLatinKeyboard(this.mSymbolsKeyboard);
                    this.mSymbolsKeyboard.setShifted(false);
                }
                updateShiftIcon();
            } else if (i != -10000) {
                if (i == -10001) {
                    this.mComposing.append("‌");
                    getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(this.mComposing, 1);
                } else if (i == -10002) {
                    this.mComposing.append("ẋ");
                    getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(this.mComposing, 1);
                } else if (i == -10003) {
                    this.mComposing.append("Ẋ");
                    getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(this.mComposing, 1);
                } else if (i == 1567) {
                    this.mComposing.append("؟");
                    getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(this.mComposing, 1);
                } else {
                    handleCharacter(i, iArr);
                }
            } else if (i == -10000) {
                btnEmoji.performClick();
            }
        }
        if (!this.sessionManager.getTransliteration().booleanValue() || !this.isEnabled) {
            this.word = "";
            this.numberOfChracters = 1;
        } else if (i == 32) {
            ll_suggessions.removeAllViews();
            sv_suggessions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_transliteration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSwitchLanguage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_LEFT);
            if (Helper.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {

                try {
                    if (stringArrayList.size() > 0) {
                        loadFirstWord(FirstWord);
                    } else {
                        loadRequest(this.word);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (this.word.toLowerCase().equals("") || this.word.toLowerCase().equals(null)) {
                getCurrentInputConnection().deleteSurroundingText(this.numberOfChracters, 0);
                getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(" ", 1);
                getCurrentInputConnection().finishComposingText();
                this.word = "";
                this.numberOfChracters = 1;
            } else {
                String sinlgeEntry = this.dataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(this.word.toLowerCase());
                getCurrentInputConnection().deleteSurroundingText(this.numberOfChracters, 0);
                InputConnection currentInputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(sinlgeEntry);
                sb.append(" ");
                Log.d("CheckGetStrin", sb.toString());
                currentInputConnection.setComposingText(sb.toString(), 1);
                getCurrentInputConnection().finishComposingText();
                this.word = "";
                this.numberOfChracters = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow. Please explain your problem in a perfect way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve NullPointerException error in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303544/how-to-solve-nullpointerexception-error-in-android)

Comment: From where you call `onPress `. Add this code also