# Why app closed suddenly when i transfer from activity to another?

Tags: android

when i trying to get back from second activity to the main activity, there is something error happens when closing the second activity.

the app in the emulator closed suddenly.

here is the code from second activity:

```
    Intent Data = new Intent();
    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nametxt = txt.getText().toString();
            String spintxt = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Data.putExtra("name" , nametxt);
            Data.putExtra("country" , spintxt);

            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK , Data);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

and here is the code from Main activity:

```
    log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this , Login2.class);
            activityResultLaunch.launch(i);
        }
    });
```

the rest of the code:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLaunch = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    name = data.getExtras().getString("name");
                    country = data.getExtras().getString("country");
                }
            }
        });
```

Edit :
the Exception from logcat tab:

```
2022-10-01 22:44:54.281 9270-9270/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 9270
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=921364964, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.Login}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must either set a text or a view
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5347)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5386)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must either set a text or a view
        at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:215)
        at android.widget.Toast.show(Toast.java:194)
        at com.example.myapplication.Login$4.onActivityResult(Login.java:89)
        at com.example.myapplication.Login$4.onActivityResult(Login.java:78)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:413)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:370)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:770)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8613)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5340)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5386) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: To find out, you need to go to the Logcat tab and look for the stacktrace of the exception that was thrown.

Comment: 2022-10-01 22:08:43.247 8303-8303/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 8303
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1363374537, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: what you mean by stack trace @CommonsWare ?

Comment: You can learn more about stack traces [here](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html), [here](https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/java-stack-trace-understanding/), [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-stack-trace), [here](https://rollbar.com/blog/java-stack-trace/#), [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-read-and-understand-a-java-stacktrace), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/115145), among other places.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the error message.

Comment: Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303544/how-to-solve-nullpointerexception-error-in-android) for tips specific to NullPointerException.

Comment: Your code in the question does not match the stack trace. You are crashing when trying to show a `Toast`, and there is no `Toast` in your question

Comment: i know , i just deleted the Toast code to reduce the size of the code and the question, it is just a message .
does it affects during the runtime ?
@CommonsWare

Comment: "does it affects during the runtime ?" -- well, if you have a bug with your `Toast`, yes. 