# Fragments not working right (possible inflation error) (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments

In `activity_main`, I have a `FrameLayout`. I want it so when I press one button, a `CalcFragment` pops up in there, and when I press another button, a `GraphFragment` pops up in there. I also want `CalcFragment` to be the thing in there when the app first starts up. I didn't make `GraphFragment` yet, because I'm still trying to get `CalcFragment` to work right.

All my code worked when I used a fragment instead of a `FrameLayout`, and manually told the fragment to show `CalcFragment`. When I use a `FrameLayout`, though, the entire app crashes.

Here's the code for the `CalcFragment.java`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class CalcFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calc, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here's the segment of code in `MainActivity.java`'s `onCreate` function which is SUPPOSED to put the `CalcFragment` in the `FrameLayout`:

```
Fragment calcFragment = new CalcFragment();
Fragment graphFragment = new GraphFragment();

FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

fragTrans.replace(R.id.frag_container, calcFragment);
fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
fragTrans.commit();
```

After that code is a bunch of code that sets the functionality of all the buttons in the `CalcFragment`. When I tried to launch the application, it gave me an error that basically says the UI elements I referenced (the ones in the fragment) don't exist. Even though, if I delete the code, the UI elements clearly DO exist. I'm guessing this is an inflation error, and for some reason the code is just having trouble inflating the UI elements from the fragment with the UI elements from the main activity. I think, I don't really know. I also tried moving all this code to the `CalcFragment.java` `onCreate` function, but that in turn spawned a whole other list of issues I can't even begin to understand. I only barely know how fragments work, I'm just doing what 2 YouTube tutorials told me was a good idea.

Please help, I have no idea what's going on. Thank you!

EDIT: here's a google drive link if you want to see anything else in the project.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E3inSfdbKkTFjX44pWBBRt545rs34C4q?usp=sharing

Or, if you don't feel like using google drive, here's every single line of code on the entire project:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.chrisscalculator2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.text.*;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.*;

import android.view.*;

import java.util.HashMap;

import complexnumbers.*;

//import android.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static int historyDepth = 100; //how many entries in equation history
    public static int clearCount = 0;     //how many times we've hit the clear button in a row
    public static boolean dotPress = false; //how many times we've hit the . button in a row (false=even, true=odd)
    public static boolean ePress = false; //how many times we've hit the e button in a row (false=even, true=odd)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        //View graphLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_layout, null);


        Fragment calcFragment = new CalcFragment();
        //Fragment graphFragment = new GraphFragment();

        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragTrans.replace(R.id.frag_container, calcFragment);
        fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        fragTrans.commit();


        final boolean[] secKeys = {false};

        EditText calc_inp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calc_input);


        calc_inp.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="1080px"
    android:layout_height="2340px"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/graph_button_1"
        android:layout_width="240px"
        android:layout_height="90px"
        android:backgroundTint="#0000FF"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Graph"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="42px"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/equations_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calc_button_1"
        android:layout_width="240px"
        android:layout_height="90px"
        android:backgroundTint="#0000FF"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Calc"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="42px"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/equations_button_1"
        android:layout_width="240px"
        android:layout_height="90px"
        android:backgroundTint="#0000FF"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Equations"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="42px"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/calc_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/equations_button_1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's fragment_calc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_calc_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".CalcFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/calc_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="135px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30px"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#00FFFF"

        android:textSize="54px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's CalcFragment.java:

```
package com.example.chrisscalculator2;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class CalcFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calc, container, false);
    }
}
```

P.S. I know I'm using pixels instead of dp. Trust me, I have a very very very very very very good reason for that.

Comment: Can you  share the  screenshot of the crash and your fragment xml ?

Comment: I don't remember how to send pictures, but I can attach the error readout and the layout.xml. :)

Comment: Your crash is happening in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method, so you'll have to post that too (the whole thing). It's saying you're calling `setShowSoftInputOnFocus` on a variable that should be an `EditText` but it's actually null, so you're probably looking up that `EditText` before you have the fragment attached. Honestly you should post the whole `MainActivity` file, it's hard to say what you're doing wrong without being able to see how you're setting things up

Comment: My code is obnoxiously long, so I trimmed out a lot of the lines and pasted it into the original post. I also made sure that the error message I got with the original code and the one I got with the shortened code is identical, bar for the PID, which was 12445 instead of 13229. That is to say, the problem described in the error message has been isolated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303544/how-to-solve-nullpointerexception-error-in-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it have some tips on debugging and solving a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm think I know why it's a nullpointerexception. It's because calc_inp wasn't successfully instantiated. Which I think is because R.id.calc_input couldn't be read. Which, if I had to guess, is because the fragment it exists in wasn't properly inflated. I just can't figure out why that is, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the info I asked for is in the edit history, I'll show you what the problem is:

```
Fragment calcFragment = new CalcFragment();

FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

fragTrans.replace(R.id.frag_container, calcFragment);
fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
fragTrans.commit();

...

EditText calc_inp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calc_input);
calc_inp.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

There's a big guide on `Fragment`s, and [here's an important bit about transactions](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#async):

> Calling `commit()` **doesn't perform the transaction immediately. Rather, the transaction is scheduled to run on the main UI thread as soon as it is able to do so.** If necessary, however, you can call `commitNow()` to run the fragment transaction on your UI thread immediately.
>
> Note that `commitNow` is incompatible with `addToBackStack`. Alternatively, you can execute all pending FragmentTransactions submitted by `commit()` calls that have not yet run by calling `executePendingTransactions()`. This approach is compatible with `addToBackStack`.

So when you call `commit()`, the `Fragment` isn't actually added yet - it happens *later*. If you immediately call `supportFragmentManager.getFragments()` you'll get an empty list, because the fragment hasn't been added yet.

If you immediately call `supportFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` then the `Fragment` *will* be added, and it will show up in the list of `Fragment`s.

---

But that's not your only problem - just because the fragment has been added, its *view* (i.e. its layout hierarchy) hasn't been inflated yet. Fragments have their own lifecycle - `onCreate`, `onCreateView` etc that they have to run through, and immediately after constructing one and adding it to your `FragmentManager`, it's not in the `CREATED` state yet.

That means you can't do `findViewById` (which you're running on the `Activity`'s layout) because the `Fragment`'s view (its layout hierarchy) hasn't been inflated yet, so no view with that ID exists in the overall layout yet. It will happen *later*. I'm being vague about that, because you can't be sure exactly when that will be, without hooking into the Fragment to check when it's ready, or other complicated things like that.

And because `Activities` and `Fragments` have their own separate lifecycles, and they can be recreated independently in any order (e.g. when you rotate the screen and everything is destroyed), you can't even be sure which will be ready when. You could observe `Lifecycle` objects but... you shouldn't need to be doing that at all, it's pretty advanced - especially when you just want to display a Fragment, the most basic stuff.

---

And if that sounds complicated, yeah - that's partly why the *Navigation* component was created, so devs don't have to worry about a lot of this stuff. But in this case, the simplest approach is to keep things separate - the `Activity` shouldn't *need* to know when the `Fragment`'s view is created. You should be able to just add the Fragment and have it work. So this:

```
calc_inp.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

could go in the *`Fragment`'s* setup, `onCreate` or whatever. It's part of the Fragment's own initialisation, right? Let it take care of its own business, wire up its own views and listeners and set things up however they're supposed to work. That way, you can just drop a `Fragment` into an `Activity` and it Just Works - the `Activity` doesn't need to go poking around in there to finish setting things up.

(There are cases where you might need to wire some stuff up so the `Activity` and `Fragment` can communicate - but is this one of them? Does the `Activity` need to be involved here? That's the mindset you need to be in - make your `Fragment`s as self-contained as possible, and leave your `Activity` as simple as possible.)

Comment: Does this mean I should put all that code about calc_inp into the CalcFragment.onCreate() ?

Comment: @MathMachine you should treat your Fragment as a self-contained component that sets itself up. Kinda think of it like the Activity is just there to display Fragments by showing them in a container - the Fragments themselves should handle their own logic, their own setup and configuration (as much as is possible). So setting a property on one of its `EditText`s should be a thing the Fragment does, right? The Fragment owns it. The Activity shouldn't need to know anything about it. And since the Fragment's setting itself up, you can do it in `onViewCreated` when you *know* you have your views

Comment: So I should put it into CalcFragment.onViewCreated?

Comment: @MathMachine I know you're working off videos but definitely have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments, and maybe something like this Codelab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-fragments#0 It's more work but this is kind of a fundamental concept in Android and it's important to get your head around, and it gets a *lot* easier once you get the idea of how it all works, and how you're *expected* to be using it. It's all designed with a certain approach in mind

Comment: If you're asking about that one line I mentioned, then yeah try it in `onViewCreated`. You can do it in `onCreateView` if you want too, if you're already implementing that function - you just need to have access to the *view* (the layout hierarchy) which you don't have in a Fragment's `onCreate`.

Comment: findViewById doesn't work in onViewCreated because it's non-static. I don't know how to obtain the instance of MainActivity this whole thing runs on, so I'm kind of against a wall here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248528/discussion-between-math-machine-and-cactustictacs).

Comment: Also, would you prefer to do this in the comments or continue the discussion in chat?

Comment: @MathMachine I can't keep helping you with this sorry, I'm just trying to give you an overview so you have somewhere to start and you can look into why it's not working. You need to run `findViewById` on the Fragment's `view` hiearchy - you can either access it through `getView()` (read the documentation to see when this works: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getView()) or use the `view` parameter that's passed into `onViewCreated`. It's a method on `View`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int) that looks for a child

Comment: Thank god it finally works. Thank you!

Comment: @MathMachine no worries! Seriously, I'd recommend going through some basic tutorials if you can - I'm not saying this stuff is *easy*, but it's *fundamental*, so getting this kind of thing down will help you a lot, and make it way less frustrating to learn. There's a bunch of stuff you need to *get* and once it clicks it's a lot easier, so learning that stuff in a structured way will make it go quicker and you'll pick up a lot of useful info. Maybe try the codelabs I linked up there. Up to you! I know it's time away from what you want to actually be doing, but uh that happens a lot! good luck✊

Comment: Everything works just as intended right now (except there's now some lag when I try to switch from the GraphFragment back to the CalcFragment). You are my hero. I could hug you right now.